# Powershell match a sub-property

Tags: powershell

It's straightforward to find an object in a list that matches a property.

```
$object1 | Get-Member
name   Property string name
id     Property int id

$listOfObjects | Where-Object name -eq "MyName"
MyName 37
```

But what if it's a sub-property?

```
$object1 | Get-Member
name    Property    list

$object1.name | Get-Member
firstName    Property    string     firstName
lastName     Property    string     lastName

$listOfObjects | Where-Object name.firstName -eq "Bob"
No results returned
```

I found such a case when managing a WSUS server through Powershell. I want to find every update with specific letters in the title. Code is below. Ellipses (...) represent redacted text. Comments (#) re my thought process.

```
$updates = Get-WsusUpdate

$updates[0]
Title        Classification    Installed...Percentage    Approved
-----        --------------    ----------------------    --------
Microsoft... Updates                                     Unapproved
#Ah, there's the title, in a property named "Title". I can filter based on Title. 
#Let's do Get-Member to get more information about Title. 

$updates[0] | Get-Member
TypeName: Microsoft.UpdateServices.Commands.WsusUpdate
...
Update    Property    Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.IUpdate Update {get;}
...
#Hmm, Title is not present in Get-Member. What if I see the members of the Update property

$updates[0].update | Get-Member
TypeName: Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.IUpdate
...
Title    Property    string title {get;set}
...
#Ah, there it is. 

$update[0].update.title
Windows Server Update Services 3.0 SP2.....
#Found it! I need to filter on $_.update.title

$update | Where_Object $_.update.title -match "Windows"
LOL No way.
```

Do you know how I can filter a list based on a sub-property like that?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using a statement such as:

```bash
$listOfObjects | Where-Object Name -EQ "MyName"
```

You're using what's called **Comparison statement** which supports a filtering such as the one above.

```bash
Where-Object <Property Name> <Comparison Operator> <Property Value>
```

However it does not support nested properties, for that you must use a **Script block** for your filtering logic:

```bash
Get-WsusUpdate | Where-Object { $_.Update.Title -match "Windows" }
```

For more details on this see the [**Description**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2#description) section from [`Where-Object` official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2).